# How can I run Perl tests and merge the results with JUnit Reports in Ant?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, ant, junit

I'd like to run Perl tests under [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) and produce XML output in a similar format to that produced by the Ant [JUnit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

I realize that the formatters [TAP::Formatter::JUnit](http://p3rl.org/TAP%3a%3aFormatter%3a%3aJUnit) and [TAP::Harness::JUnit](http://p3rl.org/TAP%3a%3aHarness%3a%3aJUnit) exist, but since I have no experience in Perl I do not know where to start.

Comment: I think perl programmers are about 100 zillion times more likely to use makefiles than ant. That's probably why you haven't received any answers. As a human, I hate being forced to deal with XML, which wasn't designed for human use but for program use.

Comment: thank you for the explanation of the situation.
anyway, i keep waiting a bit , maybe there will be someone here who has faced such a problem

Comment: I've expanded on my answer below - let me know if that's enough information, or if you need more.

Answer (score 6):

If you already have tests using `Test::More` or the like, then using `prove --formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit` is the simplest way to go. You don't change any of your Perl tests or code, and you get the JUnit output that the Java-based tools use.

We use this setup with Hudson so we can track our tests and get good test failure reports as needed from Hudson's built-in tools without a lot of contortions. Our build is `make`-based, but that's the only real difference from your setup.

This means you should be able to run `prove` as an external task and get the benefits without having to change your Ant tooling significantly, if that wasn't clear.

Depending on which Perl you have installed, you may or may not have `prove`. Run

```
perl -MTest::Harness -e'print "$Test::Harness::VERSION\n"'
```

to see which version you've got - 3.00 or better will have `prove`; ideally, you should install 3.23 to get the best functionality:

```
sudo cpan Test::Harness TAP::Formatter::JUnit
```

This installs the most recent Test::Harness, TAP::Formatter::JUnit, and all needed prerequisites. Try out the external process with

```
prove --formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit your/testsuite/directory/
```

You should get a JUnit XML file at the end of the `prove` run. If this all works, add it to Ant with

```
<target name="run">
<exec executable="prove">
  <arg value="--formatter" />
  <arg value="TAP::Formatter::JUnit" />
  <arg path="your/testsuite/directory/" />
</exec>
```

[Ant documentation for "Exec"](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

(I believe this is the correct Ant syntax for running an external program, but I'm not an Ant expert.)

Comment: I gave this a test and the "ant exec" didn't work, as ant looks for the executable as a file to run.  Seems there is a (torturous) way to list the command line arguments to the file.   For my project, my perl is in a subdir with a Makefile to run the test, so I call "make -C perl test_junit" and have the prove command in my Makefile.  I'll edit the ant syntax above to call exec with args.

Comment: using 'line' instead of 'value' would have worked, to allow since we don't have embedded spaces, but might as well go whole hog if we're in ant/xml land.  And besides, path should translate the path to work for windows or *nux environments.  'arg line ="--formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit your/testsuite/dir" '

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `TAP::Formatter::JUnit` is `TAP::Harness::JUnit`. For example:

`prove --harness TAP::Harness::JUnit t`

I found `TAP::Formatter::JUnit` didn't install on Windows, whereas `TAP::Harness::JUnit` seems to work everywhere.